# How should I call a WebService from a Windows Service Application?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, windows-services, delphi-xe5

I'm facing a annoying problem for the last couple days. I've made a Win32 application who calls some functions via WebServices. I've used the WSDL importer in order to get the WebService methods. Within the Win32 application I am able use every method to access this WebService, however I need this software to run as a Windows Service.

So I have created a Windows Service Application and added the WebService units. But now when I call these functions I get a ERemotable Exception:

[image: ERemotable Exception]

There is any difference in the process of make use of webservices from a Windows Service Application and the process used to Win32 applications?

If anyone can give me a hint, or point me some direction I'll be very glad.

PS: I am using a HTTPRIO component and Delphi XE5 in order to do this.

Comment: Did you call `CoInitialize/Ex()` in the thread that is creating the `HTTPRIO` component?  Are you trying to access the component in a different thread than the one that created it?

Comment: CoInitialize is likely culprit. Called on your behalf in GUI app. Not so in service. What user account runs the service? Also, a windows service made with delphi is a win32 app.

Comment: Sorry for not replying right away, I was making some tests. And thank you both guys for the answers, I was not calling CoInitialize in the thread who creates the HTTPRIO. Also, @DavidHeffernan thank you for the note about a service made with Delphi being a Win32 application. If any of you post as a Answer I'll be glad to select it as a correct answer.